# Faltan Items al recibir Array

Tags: java, android, json

Todo me funciona correctamente recogiendo tan solo los valores de un array, pero al recoger los datos de los dos que es lo que quiero,me faltan datos, como puedo hacerlo para tenerlos en el mismo activity:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        urlPost = url[0];
        try {
            jsonObjectDesignPosts = JsonParser.readJsonFromUrl(urlPost);
            postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").length();
            jsonArrayDesignContent = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal");

            postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").length();
            jsonArrayDesignContent = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante");

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("DESIGN", jsonArrayDesignContent.toString()).apply();
            designNombre_local = new String[postNumber];
            designMinuto_local = new String[postNumber];

            designNombre_visitante = new String[postNumber];
            designMinuto_visitante = new String[postNumber];


            for (int i = 0; i < postNumber; i++) {

                designNombre_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
                designMinuto_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();
                designNombre_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
                designMinuto_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();

            }

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            designNombre_local = new String[0];
            error = true;
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    designs = new ArrayList<>();


    if (designNombre_local.length != -1) {


        for(int i=0; i<(designNombre_local.length); i++){

            designs.add(new Goles(designNombre_local[i],designMinuto_local[i],
                    designNombre_visitante[i],designMinuto_visitante[i]));
        }
    }
    if (error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Me he dado cuenta de que muestra el numero de items inferior, me explico, en el partido han marcado los locales 5 y los visitantes 3, pues muestra solo tres resultados de cada equipo.
¿A que se debe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al dimensionar cuantos valores obtendrás de tu array estas considerando que `postNumber` tiene el mismo valor para local y visitante, aunqúe `golesLocal` fueran más o menos al final estas tomando el valor de `golesVisitante`:

```
postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").length();
postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").length();
```

El problema sucede aquí :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < postNumber; i++) {

        designNombre_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
        designMinuto_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();
        designNombre_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
        designMinuto_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();

    }
```

incluso podrías tener el error:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Como solución, se debería tomar un valor `postNumber` de `golesLocal` y otro de  `postNumber` para `golesVisitante`, esto para dimensionar la obtención correcta de valores, ejemplo:

```
//Obtiene valores Local.
    postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").length();


        for (int i = 0; i < postNumber; i++) {

            designNombre_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
            designMinuto_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();

        }

//Obtiene valores Visitante.
    postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").length();

        for (int i = 0; i < postNumber; i++) {

            designNombre_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
            designMinuto_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema creo esta aqui `postNumber` en esta variable asignacion/reasignacion.

pseudo code:

```
//..
//se marcan 5 goles
postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").length();

//ahora se marcan 3   
postNumber = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").length();
```

y ahora aqui cuantos se muestran ->

```
for (int i = 0; i < postNumber; i++) {

     designNombre_local[i]     = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
     designMinuto_local[i]     = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();
     designNombre_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre")).toString();
     designMinuto_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").getJSONObject(i).getString("minuto")).toString();

}
```

El ultimo valor que se le asigno que es 3 por ejemplo.(solo iterara 3 veces por eso en este caso te faltan goles de un equipo)

Espero me entiendas, puedes solucionarlo de muchas maneras si el error es el que te indico (no lo he podido testear), podrias crear dos variables `postNumberLocal` y `postNumberVisitiante` e iterarlas por separadao osea un `for` por ejemplo para cada varariable pero solo es una idea.

```
for (int i = 0; i < postNumberLocal; i++) {

     designNombre_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal")
                               .getJSONObject(i)
                               .getString("nombre")).toString();

     designMinuto_local[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal")
                               .getJSONObject(i)
                               .getString("minuto")).toString();

}

for (int i = 0; i < postNumberVisitiante; i++) {


     designNombre_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante")
                               .getJSONObject(i)
                               .getString("nombre")).toString();

     designMinuto_visitante[i] = Html.fromHtml(jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante")
                               .getJSONObject(i)
                               .getString("minuto")).toString();

}
```

Ahora ajustamos las nuevas variables

```
//.. 
//se marcan 5 goles
postNumberLocal      = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesLocal").length();
//..
//ahora se marcan 3   
postNumberVisitiante = jsonObjectDesignPosts.getJSONArray("golesVisitante").length();
//..
```

Y tambien en el momento de determinar el tamaño de los arrays que usas algo asi:

```
//..

..//
designNombre_local     = new String[postNumberLocal];
designMinuto_local     = new String[postNumberLocal];
designNombre_visitante = new String[postNumberVisitante];
designMinuto_visitante = new String[postNumberVisitante];
..//
```

Comment: Se adetenido la aplicacion, logcat: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Answer (score 0):

Usted me comenta ->

> Se adetenido la aplicacion, logcat:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

eso ocurre basicamente porque esta intentando acceder fuera de los limites del array (en este caso) simple ilustracion:

- El tamaño de su array digamos que es de 3.
- Y usted esta intentado acceder a la posicion(indice) 3.

Aparentemete puede pensar que esta bien, pero en muchos lenguajes el indexado es desde 0, eso quiere decir que cuenta desde el 0.

```
 para la longitud        el indice maximo es 
    1                          0
    2                          1
    3                          2
```

.

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior usted esta empleando en algun momento para la `longitud = 3` un acceso al `indice 3` del array, como puede ver en la tabla anterior el maximo para 3 es de 2, de ahi su error.

Ahora como solucionarlo yo no se donde se produce exactamente el error a simple vista basandome en el log que muestra, pues no puedo ver aque linea se refiere, pero creo que entendiendo lo anterior usted puede averiguar donde esta el error, (en la salida del log, es muy probable que le indique un numero digamos 10 pues usted se dirije a la linea diez de su codigo y busca el error por ahi, esto seria una forma simple de encontrar el error).

Pero si tengo que decir donde creo que esta el error es posible que sea en esta parte del codigo:

```
  if (designNombre_local.length != -1) {


    for(int i=0; i<(designNombre_local.length); i++){

        designs.add(new Goles(designNombre_local[i],designMinuto_local[i],
                designNombre_visitante[i],designMinuto_visitante[i]));
    }
```

Mas concretamente es esta linea:

> designNombre_visitante[i],designMinuto_visitante[i]));

es posible que el tamaño de `designNombre_visitante` sea diferente (mas pequeño) que `designNombre_local.length` de ahi que en algun punto la variable `i` intente acceder fuera del indice del array `designNombre_visitante`

el como solucionarlo exactamente de ser ese el error, teniendo en cuenta cual es el motivo del error, tendria que saber que es lo que usted esta intendo hacer con:

```
designs.add(new Goles(designNombre_local[i],designMinuto_local[i],
                    designNombre_visitante[i],designMinuto_visitante[i]));
```

Y de que manera es usado (tratando o ajustandolo de alguna manera para que no se intente acceder a una posicion no valida de array).

P.D: como nota tambien le dire que usted puede estar asumiendo que designNombre_local.length, simpre es mayor que designNombre_visitante,

```
for(int i=0; i<(designNombre_local.length); i++){
```

pero no se si esa es su intentecion, pero de no ser asi tenerlo en cuenta cuando haga los cambios para solucionar el error anterior.

Comment: La verdad no lo se pero sin el  designs.add(new Goles(designNombre_local[i],designMinuto_local[i],
                    designNombre_visitante[i],designMinuto_visitante[i])); dentro del protected void onPostExecute(String result) { no me muestra ningun valor. Mi email Rafelcf@gmail.com